# Modify part of dataframe's column value based on some other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to update/modify certain part of data frame based on another column's value.

If column `['a']`  is null, fill column `['a']` with value of column `['b']` like below

```
list_position = [[4, 35]]
df.iloc[list_position[0][0]:list_position[0][1] + 1,:]['a'] = df.iloc[list_position[0][0]:list_position[0][1] + 1,:].apply(lambda row: row['a'] * row['b'] if np.isnan(row['a']) else row['b'], axis=1)
```

It is giving error as `TypeError: an integer is required`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Any suggestion to correct the same is highly appreciated.

Update 1. I tried all three ways as suggested in 
1 duplicate answer

```
df['Cat1'].fillna(df['Cat2'])
```

and

2 answers suggested on this post.

```
1. df['a'][df['a'].isnull()] = df['b']
2. df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(df['b'])
```

All are giving same error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in 
pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in 
pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
TypeError: an integer is required
```

It is working if I replace column name with column number like

```
df[7] = df[7].fillna(df[8)
```

Not sure why, if any one has explanation for same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the logic that you are trying to use to complete the task, but there is a much easier way to do it.

```
df['a'] = df['a'].fillna(df['b'])
```

This will fill the null values in column a with the values in column b on the same index. However if column b has null values and column a has null values column a will also have null.

Comment: TypeError: an integer is required same error with this statement.

Comment: Can you post your code in the comment? I think it has something to do with the quotations making the compiler believe that there are strings being passed through but I can't tell without seeing how you are actually using the code above. Tested it on my code earlier and it worked

Comment: temp_df['ESTIMATED_TIME'] = temp_df['ESTIMATED_TIME'].fillna(temp_df['IF_ARRIVED'])

Comment: I am exacly using same line you suggested, just replacing the name of df and columns

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
TypeError: an integer is required

Comment: Can you check the datatype of estimated time and if arrived and post them here? Like this:

temp_df.dtypes

Comment: Its empty after 'Like this :' do you want to suggest how to see datatype?

Comment: temp_df.dtypes is what it should say. Shows that on my comment, weird

Comment: 0      object
1      object
2      object
3      object
4      object
5      object
6      object
7      object
8      object
9      object
10     object
11     object
12    float64
13     object
dtype: object

Comment: It is returning object. But I am receiving it in as argument like temp_df : pd.DataFrame.

Comment: Click the link to talk to me in chat. I know the issue but its better to use chat for extended discussions.  [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187590/discussion-between-edeki-okoh-and-manvi).

Comment: strangely same statement is working if I replace column name with column number. df[7] = df[7].fillna(df[8)

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Can you please suggest which panda version are you using.  I suspect its the difference in version.

Comment: I am using '0.23.4'

Comment: OK. I have same version. what do you get with print(df.columns.values.tolist()). I get column numbers like this [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] instead of name..

Comment: That just means you haven't given your column headers any names yet.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in your case

```
df['a'][df['a'].isnull()] = df['b']
```

Comment: I don't think so. Test out `print(np.nan==np.nan)`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 958, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item
TypeError: an integer is required
 Error with this statement.